# How to create a auto incremented column in Documentdb

Tags: c#, auto-increment, azure-cosmosdb

I want to create a document in azure documentdb with an auto-increment column.

Is this possible? If yes, please guide me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Database db = CreateOrReadDocumentDb("EmployeeDb").Result;
DocumentCollection dc = CreateOrReadDocumentCollection(db.SelfLink, "EmployeeDetails").Result;
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.Name="ABC";
emp.id="";//automatically generate a unique string
emp.sal=10000;
emp.exp =5;
emp.index=0; // I want an auto increment column for emp with name index and want to store in azure document db
 client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, data);
```

Comment: not exactly, I will edit my question :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do we have Identity Column in DocumentDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701587/do-we-have-identity-column-in-documentdb)

Comment: thanks Abdel Raoof :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DocumentDB doesn't include auto-increment functionality out of the box.

As Gaurav mentioned in [Do we have Identity Column in DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701587/do-we-have-identity-column-in-documentdb), the `id` field is special in that if a value isn't provided by the application - DocumentDB will assign a GUID automatically.

If you need the auto-increment functionality, one potential solution would be to store a counter as a document and leverage [DocumentDB's triggers](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/) to populate your field and update the counter.

Comment: A solution with triggers and a counter document would only work within the boundaries of a single collection. If you want to scale-out later and partition the data over multiple collections, this will become tricky. Just something one should think about before considering this solution. Of course, within a single collection, aliuy's solution is fine.

Comment: It seems that there's no access to the collection object inside a trigger, so this unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: You can access the collection object inside a trigger via `getContext().getCollection()`. Here's an example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/triggers/UpdateMetadata.js